# StackDriver: Collecting metrics from outside GCP and AWS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

My question is about StackDriver from Google Cloud. I've tried for a lot of hours to configure a server from outside of GCP and AWS to collect metrics, and I'm not able to make it work.

StackDriver is able to collect metrics from outside or I'm loosing my time?

If is able, someone knows a good manual?

Thanks!!! and greetings!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adam is correct that Stackdriver doesn't (at time of writing) support the agent metric collection outside of GCP/AWS. So what you're trying to do is not officially supported.

However, Stackdriver products are composed of APIs so you technically can collect from metrics from outside GCP and AWS. It's technically possible, but the client side tooling and docs to do so just don't exist, which will make it pretty challenging.

In general, the AWS docs are the closest to what you'll want to look at, since AWS is the public internet as far as Stackdriver is concerned.

For authentication, you'll want to use service accounts, similar to the AWS setup.

If you just have a few metrics, you could always write [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/) using one of the client libraries. That's probably the simplest thing to do if you just have a few metrics you want to write.

The collectd agent that the docs instruct you to install just gather up metrics from various logs and sends them to the API. You can check it out on [Github](https://github.com/Stackdriver/collectd?files=1). But since currently only GCP and AWS are supported, you are venturing into territory where you'll have to understand the agent's code and modify it yourself to get it working outside GCP/AWS.

I would keep an eye on Stackdriver in the future for improvements in this space.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is just what I thought, but I'm very new in GCP world and i wanted to ask to people with more experience. Greetings!!

Answer (score 2):

This is available now.  Google had some agents they provided for doing just this from different environments.

However, it looks like those are now deprecated and have been replaced with a third party (a Google Partner), from Google Docs:
https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/deprecations/third-party-apps

It looks like there is no license fee to use (free in [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bluemedora/bindplane)) just have to pay for the data usage coming into Stackdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the StackDriver agent [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/) it looks like this is not an option.

It works with AWS but you need to link your AWS account with their accounts.

Edit: I had an assumption in terms of accessing StackDriver backend from outsite authorized cloud providers. It wasn't accurate.

Comment: This answer isn't quite correct, because the services are exposed to the "open internet", they are protected by authentication. You can use Stackdriver outside of GCP/AWS, it's just a matter of the tooling and docs not being as polished at the current time.

Comment: Which tutorial, source are you trying to follow?

Comment: You are correct in that it's not supported because the docs/tooling are not ready. I'm just noting that you *can* use Stackdriver outside of GCP/AWS, currently, your comment about the "open internet" is what's not correct (AWS is already the "open internet" as far as GCP is concerned). But trying to use it today you will have to figure out a lot on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Greetings!!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this use case work, although it is not "supported" and as such for configuration of the agent I didn't really find any documentation about it other than [c source](https://github.com/Stackdriver/collectd) of stackdriver-agent.

My use case, and I assume the question, is that I have a project on GCP, possibly with some compute VMs, with enabled stackdriver, but I also have a machine outside of GCP that is somehow integrated with the rest of project that I want to monitor (just disk/cpu/memory for now).

On the machine (outside of GCP that is to be monitored) [install](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/monitoring/installation) the agent, add a service account key, described [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/monitoring/authorization).

Configure an agent by editing `/etc/stackdriver/collectd.conf` - add

```
  CloudProvider "gcp"
  Instance "name_for_machine_outside_gcp"
  Zone "europe-west3-c"
  Region "europe-west3"
```

to a `<Plugin "write_gcm">` tag, where `name_for_machine_outside_gcp` is a name of the machine for identifying metrics. Zone and Region are to my knowledge irrelevant, but has to be valid zones (where a VM in GCP can be) - as the agent is intended to run in VM inside GCP.

restart the agent `sudo service stackdriver-agent restart` and agent should start sending metrics to stackdrive, all of which are prefixed `agent.googleapis.com`.

This means that the metric will be the same as the stackdriver-agent on VM in GCP, no need to separate metrics from "my machine" into some custom metric.

This is a bit hacky as Instance field is supposed to refer an existing VM in GCP, and might collide if not careful, but I didn't find any issues with that  yet.

Other solution is BindPlane mentioned in AlphaPapa's answer, which I did not try as it seemed a bit heavywight for my simple OS metrics, but does seem like a go to solution, if metrics for some of many applications they have support for, are needed. It sends custom metrics, so metrics from GPC VM and other machines are separated.