# Is it possible to use stackdriver monitoring in an on-premise machine?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to collect cpu and memory metrics with Stackdriver monitoring on my machine, which is neither on GCP or AWS, is it doable?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767215/stackdriver-collecting-metrics-from-outside-gcp-and-aws?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

As of today, for on-prem monitoring with Stackdriver you can define and collect your own **Custom Metrics** (e.g.: [using Open Census](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/open-census) ).

You'll need to collect them with your own agent, though.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, there is currently no support for Stackdriver monitoring on premises.  Today, only compute hosted on GCP or AWS can push metrics to Stackdriver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Google Cloud Platform third party partner application BindPlane.

From Google blog:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/extending-stackdriver-to-on-prem-with-the-newbindplane-integration

Looks like it supports Windows and a couple flavors of linux - currently in Alpha.
https://docs.bindplane.bluemedora.com/docs/host

Answer (score 0):

Stackdriver leverages BindPlane for on-prem metric and log monitoring.  It's a separate SaaS service but doesn't cost anything additional.

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/blue-medora